# Comunicación entre componentes docker compose

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

Tengo una aplicacion el Laravel y otra en React que quiero automatizar con Docker. En el docker compose tengo todos los containers necesarios: php, nginx, mysql y estoy agregando tambien composer, pero tengo el problema que al correr el dockerfile y hacer composer install tira el siguiente error:

the command '/bin/sh -c composer install' returned a non-zero code: 127

El docker compose:

```
  version: '3.7'

services:
### PHP Container #########################################
  nadal:
    container_name: findra_nadal
    hostname: nadal
    build:
      context: ./nadal
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/html/app
    volumes:
      - ./nadal:/var/www/html/app
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - redis
    networks:
      - backend

### NGINX Container #########################################
  nginx:
    container_name: findra_nginx
    hostname: nginx
    image: nginx:1.17
    tty: true
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - nadal
    ports:
      - 5023:80
    volumes:
      - nadal:/var/www/html/app
      - ./nadal/docker/virtualhost.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks:
      - backend
### MySQL Container #########################################
  mysql:
    container_name: findra_mysql
    hostname: mysql
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: nadal
      MYSQL_USER: nadal-user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 33069:3306
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
#      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - backend

### Redis Container #########################################
  redis:
    container_name: findra_redis
    hostname: redis
    image: redis:5.0
    expose:
      - 6379
    networks:
      - backend

### Composer Container #########################################
  composer:
    container_name: findra_composer
    hostname: composer
    image: composer:1.8
    command: ["install --ignore-platform-reqs", "dump-autoload --optimize"]
    volumes:
      - ./nadal:/var/www/html/app
    networks:
      - backend


### Networks Setup ##########################################
networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge

### Volumes Setup ##########################################
volumes:
  nadal:
  mysql-data:
    driver: "local"
  nginx-data:
    driver: "local"
```

y el dockerfile estoy probando que ande y tengo lo siguiente:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

MAINTAINER AsadoDev

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install


# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www/html/app

WORKDIR /var/www/html/app

RUN composer install

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Comment: el dockerfile te funciona? nginx usa el puerto 80 por defecto no se porque expones el puerto 9000 por otro lado en el docker compose te falta exponer los puertos donde se van a visualizar debes hacer algo como : `ports:
     - "80:80"`

Comment: @JackNavaRow ahi edite el post. 9000 porque vi en internet, estoy aprendiendo recien esto. y nginx uso el puerto 5023:80 porque tengo varios proyectos y se pisa el host, alguna recomendacion?

Comment: Si, el mismo error al construir

Comment: antes del copy crea la carpeta `mkdir -p /var/www/html/app` despues del WORKDIR ejecuta `RUN /var/www/html/app` y luego el composer install

Comment: tep 15/20 : RUN /var/www/html/app
 ---> Running in 254ce3f264d3
/bin/sh: 1: /var/www/html/app: Permission denied
ERROR: Service 'nadal' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c /var/www/html/app' returned a non-zero code: 126.

Comment: Tampoco me copia el .env.example:

COPY --chown=root:www-data ./.env.example /var/www/html/app/.env

Comment: La imagen tiene instalado composer? quizás haría falta en el Dockerfile algo como `apt-get install composer` y luego antes del `RUN composer install` hacer un RUN `cd /var/www/html/app`

Answer (score 0):

no se en que sistema operativo están basadas esas imágenes, pero la siguiente linea puede ayudarte

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

saludos